# Average rate for 20 years, 10 years, and 5 years in R

Tags: r, average

I am trying to find the average rate of a certain virus between 2002-2021, 2002-2012, and 2002-2007 by another variable "jurisdiction". The code I have right now is:

```
avgrate20 <- ratesmerge %>%
  group_by(Jurisdiction) %>%
  summarize(
    Years = paste(range(2002:2021), collapse = "-"),
    across(starts_with("rate"), mean)
  )
```

When I change `Years = paste(range(2002:2021), collapse = "-")` to 2002-2012, it still takes the mean from 2002-2021.

Here is my output when doing `head(df)`
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thank you for providing your code! Instead of a picture of your data, it's much more helpful if you provide example data in a form we can copy and paste. Either using your actual data or similar dummy data, run `dput(data)` and copy and paste the results from the R console right into your question.

Comment: No problem at all and I appreciate that! Still trying to learn how to use stack overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Years = paste(range(yrs_wanted), collapse = "-")` simply creates a column called `Years` containing the character vector `"2002-2021"` -- this doesn't tell R anything about what rows to include in computing the mean. For that, you need to `dplyr::filter()`.

```
library(dplyr)

yrs_wanted <- 2002:2021

avgrate20 <- ratesmerge %>%
  filter(MMWR_YEAR %in% yrs_wanted) %>%
  group_by(Jurisdiction) %>%
  summarize(
    Years = paste(range(yrs_wanted), collapse = "-"),
    across(starts_with("rate"), mean)
  )
```

If you want to get fancy, you can loop through your year ranges using `purrr::map_dfr()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

year_ranges <- list(
  2002:2021,
  2002:2012,
  2002:2007
)

avgrates <- map_dfr(
  year_ranges,
  ~ ratesmerge %>%
  filter(MMWR_YEAR %in% .x) %>%
  group_by(Jurisdiction) %>%
  summarize(
    Years = paste(range(.x), collapse = "-"),
    across(starts_with("rate"), mean)
  )
)
```